# Can't send SMTP e-mail

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I am trying to test sending out an e-mail from vb.net. I am sending an e-mail from mygmail account to myself, however I keep getting an error message: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

```
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
   SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
   SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("MYEMAILADDRESS", "MYPASSWORD")
   Dim mail As New MailMessage("MYEMAILADDRESS", "MYEMAILADDRESS", "This is my Title", "This is my Email")
   SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

I have read a few post but all of them say change the port. I have changed the port however it doesn't seem to work. If I change the port it gives a similar error.

Comment: There could be a couple causes for this message. Are you sure your username and password is correct? Does your Gmail account have 2-factor authentication?

Comment: positive, just login to make sure

Comment: Ahhh, I think that there is some security around gmail. I created a new account and used that account and it works